# How do you spot the difference between an A320 and a B737?

Tags: aircraft-identification, airplane

I'm constantly having problems with identifying aircraft, and was wondering whether there are any tricks with easily identifying whether an aircraft was a Boeing 737 or Airbus A320?

Comment: For Captain Joe’s list of differences, see   https://youtu.be/RNinfd8NJHI